# CSS help aligning with photo and ul list items

Tags: html, css

I am working on creating a custom tooltip plug-in and am having trouble with the CSS and HTML layout of it.

I would like to have something like this:
[image]

Nested inside some `div` container.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Y2E36/1/) is a JSFiddle of what I have at the moment, but as you can see - I'm having some issues.

Thanks to all you CSS gurus!

Comment: Simple padding/margin to the elements would do the trick to position them correctly I suppose

Comment: Think of this as multiple `<div>`s floated to the left. In the container have these `div`s: Yellow Bar, Picture, Icons, Info.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the updates JSFiddle I made for you: http://jsfiddle.net/Y2E36/2/ All I did was add `Display:inline-block;` to `status-icons`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic re-creation for you.

**Fixed h2 closing tag**

[Have a jsbin example!](http://jsbin.com/ninata/1/edit)

HTML

```
 <div class="contact">
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/100X120/FFFFFF" />

    <div class="actions">
      <a href="#" class="phone"></a>
      <a href="#" class="email"></a>
      <a href="#" class="contact"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="details">
      <h1>John Smock</h1>
      <h2>In since Thursday, 5/9/2013 at 9:45 AM</h2>

        <p><span>Lync (Away 5 Min)</span> Lenexa</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: Helvetica;
}
.contact {
    height: 120px;
    width: 450px;
    background: #ccc;
    border-top: solid 1px #000;
}
.contact img {
    border-left: solid 12px orange;
    border-right: solid 1px #000;
    float: left;
}
.actions {
    float: left;
    border-right: solid 1px #000;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0
}
.actions a {
    background: url(http://www.placehold.it/20/FFFFFF) no-repeat;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    display: block;
    margin: 15px 13px;
    border: none;
}
.details h1 {
    font-size: 1em;
    padding: 8px 0 5px;
}
.details h2 {
    font-size: 0.8em;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 3px;
}
.details p {
    font-size: 0.8em;
    margin: 48px 0 0;
}
.details span {
    padding: 0 5px 0 0;
    border-right: solid 1px #000;
}
```